# JavaFX ImageView resize in StackPane

Tags: imageview, javafx-2

I have a ploblem with resizing of ImageView in StackPane:
If StackPane is root container and I bind image's height and width to StackPane, everything is fine.

```
<StackPane id="StackPane" fx:id="stack" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgreen;" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication8.FXMLController">
  <children>
    <ImageView fx:id="image" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="300.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@fxml.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</StackPane>
```

But if I place such stack pane in, for example, grid, than image doesnt resize properly.
As I read, the problem that ImageView is non-Resizable. Is there any ways to make it resizable? Or could you give some advise how to resize ImageView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to create a background image for the StackPane.  In which case applying the image via CSS may be a better route to use than an ImageView.

```
.stack-pane {
  -fx-background-image: url("flower.png");
  -fx-background-size: cover;
}
```

See the [background images](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) section of the Region specification in the JavaFX CSS reference guide.

Making [ImageView itself resizable is an unresolved major issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091789). The issue links to [code for a simple workaround](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091216) - a resizable ImagePane wrapping an Image to fill the resizable pane.

Comment: Thanks a lot!) I wanted to create background image or video, your link helped me a lot. Workaround that suitable for me is resizable pane, that contains MediaView or ImageView.